# How to prove sum related to hyperbolic tangents $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\tanh(...)}{1+\frac{\tanh^2x}{\tan^2(....)}}=\tanh(2nx)$

Tags: summation, hyperbolic-functions, hypergeometric-function

I have no Idea how to start

I think to switch it to definite integral, use complex analysis, or some real analysis tricks and at the end I failed to make any progress.

$$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{\tanh \left( \dfrac x{n \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{2k+1}{4n} \pi\right)}\right)}{1 + \dfrac{\tanh^2 x}{\tan^2 \left( \dfrac{2k+1}{4n} \pi\right)}} = \tanh(2n x ) $$

Comment: There must be some typos somewhere. In its current form, it is not true even for $n = 1$.

Comment: The correct expression to prove should be $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{\dfrac{\tanh x}{n \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{2k+1}{4n} \pi\right)}}{1 + \dfrac{\tanh^2 x}{\tan^2 \left( \dfrac{2k+1}{4n} \pi\right)}} = \tanh(2n x )$$

Comment: I'm still in the dark, but I've verified achille hui's corrected identity by hand for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$. I replaced $2x$ by $x$,and simplified the identity to $$\frac{n\tanh(nx)}{\sinh x} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\cosh x - \cos\left(\frac{2k+1}{2n}\pi\right)}$$

Comment: Hint: $\;\tanh(x) = \log\cosh(x)'\;$ and $\cosh(mx) = T_{m}(\cosh x)$ where $$T_m(x) = 2^{m-1}\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\left[x - \cos\left(\frac{2k+1}{2m}\pi\right)\right]$$ is the [Chebyshev's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of first kind.

Comment: @achillehui D'oh! :)